# Rails polymorphic associations - has_many condition error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, has-many-polymorphs

I'm using rails 3.2.8 and i'm having some troubles with polymorphic associations.
I have a model activity that it is polymorphic that is related with another polymorphic model contribution that can be an asset_file, biography, dynamic_annotation or a citation.

So the grandfather is the activity...the father is the contribution and finally the sons (of contributions) are biographies, asset_file, dynamic_annotations or citations.

I my model thing that aggregate all of those concepts i have the next code:

```
  has_many :activities, 
           :order => 'created_at DESC', 
           :dependent =>:delete_all

  has_many :contributions,
           :through => :activities,
           :source => :activable,
           :source_type => "Contribution"

  has_many :dynamic_annotations,
           :through => :contributions,
           :source => :contributable,
           :source_type => "DynamicAnnotation",
           :conditions => {"contributions.c_state" => "ACCEPTED"}

  has_many :biographies,
           :through => :contributions,
           :source => :contributable,
           :source_type => "Biography",
           :conditions => {"contributions.c_state" => "ACCEPTED"}

  has_many :citations,
           :through => :contributions,
           :source => :contributable,
           :source_type => "Citation",
           :conditions => {"contributions.c_state" => "ACCEPTED"}

  has_many :asset_files,
           :through => :contributions,
           :source => :contributable,
           :source_type => "AssetFile",
           :conditions => {"contributions.c_state" => "ACCEPTED"}
```

The problem:
I opened the console and I typed the next query:

```
Thing.first.biographies
```

The sql that I got:

```
SELECT `biographies`.* FROM `biographies` INNER JOIN `contributions` ON `biographies`.`id` = `contributions`.`contributable_id` INNER JOIN `activities` ON `contributions`.`id` = `activities`.`activable_id` WHERE `activities`.`thing_id` = 1 AND `activities`.`activable_type` = 'Contribution' AND (`contributions`.`c_state` = 'ACCEPTED') AND (`contributions`.`contributable_type` = 'Biography')
```

That is a correct answer

Then i typed after the command:

```
Thing.first.dynamic_annotations
```

The sql that I got:

```
SELECT `dynamic_annotations`.* FROM `dynamic_annotations` INNER JOIN `contributions` ON `dynamic_annotations`.`id` = `contributions`.`contributable_id` INNER JOIN `activities` ON `contributions`.`id` = `activities`.`activable_id` WHERE `activities`.`thing_id` = 1 AND `activities`.`activable_type` = 'Contribution' AND (`contributions`.`c_state` = 'ACCEPTED') AND (`contributions`.`contributable_type` = 'Biography' AND `contributions`.`contributable_type` = 'DynamicAnnotation')
```

I got a void result because the object cannot have two types of corse.

If someone can help me with that i will apreciate :)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I found a rails issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3882 with a workaround from "alarribeau" that solve the problem. This is not a fix but it can help you.